# How to produce a popup message depending on user input in tkinter on python?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, popupwindow

I am trying to create a system wherein, the user can enter the current temperature and the desired temperature using two sliders. When both the temperatures are confirmed by pressing the button `"Set"`, a popup message should appear dependent on user input.

- If the desired temperature is higher than the current temperature,
  this popup message should show: `"Turn the heater on?"`.
- If the desired temperature is lower than the current temperature,
  this popup message should show: "`Turn the cooler on?"`

I have tried to produce this but my code doesn't seem to be producing anything upon clicking the `"Set"` button. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label1=ttk.Label(self,text="Smart Thermostat",font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Current Temperature:",font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        slider1 = tk.Scale(self, from_=10, to = 30, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        slider1.pack()

        label3 = ttk.Label(self, text="Set to:",font=MEDIUM_FONT)
        label3.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        slider2 = tk.Scale(self, from_=18, to = 25, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        slider2.pack()

        def popupmsg1(msg):
            popup1=tk.Tk()
            popup1.wm_title("!")
            label4 = ttk.Label(popup1, text="Turn heater on?", font = MEDIUM_FONT)
            label4.pack(side = "top", fill = "x", pady=10)
            button2=ttk.Button(popup1, text="Okay", command = popup1.destroy)
            button2.pack()
            popup1.mainloop()

        def popupmsg2(msg):
            popup2=tk.Tk()
            popup2.wm_title("!")
            label5 = ttk.Label(popup2, text="Turn cooler on?", font = MEDIUM_FONT)
            label5.pack(side = "top", fill = "x", pady=10)
            button3=ttk.Button(popup2, text="Okay", command = popup2.destroy)
            button3.pack()
            popup2.mainloop()    

        def popupmsg():
            temp=int(slider2.get())
            need=int(slider1.get())
            if temp<need:
                popup1=tk.Tk()
            else:
                popup2=tk.Tk()


        button1=tk.Button(self, text="Set", command= lambda: popupmsg)
        button1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please include only the relevant parts. We can't help you if you dump a whole library here :)

Comment: I really do apologise, I am new here. Thank you for your suggestion, appreciate it :)

Comment: Please provide a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future readers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have mentioned above that I am new here but nevertheless I apologise again for not meeting standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create your messages / dialog using the info below:

```
 # Python 3
 from tkinter import messagebox

 # Python 2
 import tkMessageBox as messagebox

 if case 1:
      messagebox.showinfo("title 1", "message 1")
 else:
      messagebox.showinfo("title 2", "message 2")
```

You typically only spawn custom windows for really custom info boxes / windows that do their own logic. For simple messages it suffices to use the built in message box. Even then you should just use `Toplevel` instead of spawning entirely new `tk.Tk` instances. Tk is just one big mainloop (hence using .mainloop()....) which processes events within it.

How you choose to display messages to a user is really open-ended you could even make a label that updates the text and shows / hides it appropriately etcetera.

If you want to do custom fonts etcetera which it looks like... without digging through all of your code... you'd actually have to go the Toplevel / widget route.

Comment: "Even then you <strikethrough>could</strikethrough>should just": Spawning multiple `Tk` instances is very bad practice.

Comment: @Coal_ Agreed... Thought the should was implied given the rest / fact it was mentioned. Nonetheless I'll update for clarity.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that! Really grateful for your help :)